# Service.Controller Status / Polling

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I'm having a problem with a administrative app I'm working on.  I'm build an interface for stopping, starting and querying various services across 40 or so servers.

I'm looking at service.controller and have been successful in stopping and starting various services with button events but now I'm trying to figure out a way to return the service status to a text box and query for service status every 10 seconds or so and I feel like I'm hitting a brick wall.

Does anyone have any tips or insight?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger the periodic service check by using a Timer object. You can run your service queries on the Elapsed event.

```
    private void t_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check service statuses
    }
```

As for displaying statuses in a text box, you should be able to use the ToString() method on the service status and display that in a regular text box. Remember that you may or may not be on the GUI thread when reacting to the timer events, so you'll need to invoke yourself on to the main thread.

```
    private delegate void TextUpdateHandler(string updatedText);

    private void UpdateServerStatuses(string statuses)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            TextUpdateHandler update = new TextUpdateHandler(this.UpdateServerStatuses);
            this.BeginInvoke(update, statuses);
        }
        else
        {
            // load textbox here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't want to poll:

```
Private serviceController As ServiceController = Nothing 
Private serviceControllerStatusRunning = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        serviceController = New ServiceController("NameOfTheTheServiceYouWant")
        If serviceController.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped Then
            ' put code for stopped status here
        Else
            ' put code for running status here
        End If
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error:" + ex.Message)
        serviceController = Nothing
        Me.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    If serviceControllerStatusRunning Then
        serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
        serviceControllerStatusRunning = False
    Else
        serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        serviceControllerStatusRunning = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
     if serviceControllerStatusRunning then
       ' put code for running status here
     else
       ' put code for stopped status here
     end if
     BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() ' start worker thread again
End Sub
```

Cheers
 Evolved